# ¿Como eliminar un elemento especifico de un array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo: `[1,2,3,4,5]` y quiero eliminar un elemento en particular.

He logrado esto, pero supongo que hay otras formas mas simples en javascript para lograrlo.

```js
function eliminar(array, elemento) {
  var resultado = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== elemento) {
      resultado.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

array = eliminar(array, 3);

console.log( array );
```

¿Que formas provee el lenguaje para hacer esto?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hay varias formas de eliminar elementos en javascript.

### Array.prototype.splice

Para usar este metodo, se debe conocer el indice del elemento a eliminar.

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];

var indice = arreglo.indexOf(3); // obtenemos el indice
arreglo.splice(indice, 1); // 1 es la cantidad de elemento a eliminar

console.log( arreglo );
```

### Array.prototype.filter

Este método se introdujo en EcmaScript 5, utilizando filter

Versión para EcmaScript 5:

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];

arreglo = arreglo.filter(function(i) { return i !== 3 }); // filtramos

console.log( arreglo );
```

Versión para EcmaScript 2015:

```js
var arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5];

arreglo = arreglo.filter((i) => i !== 3); // filtramos

console.log( arreglo );
```