# Eliminar elemento array y se muevan los demás hacia la izquierda

Tags: javascript, array

Hola me gustaría saber como poder eliminar un elemento de un array y que se muevan todos hacia la izquierda.

```
var j = ['coche','mesa','silla','autobús'];
```

Me gustaría que si elimino mesa la posición 1 la ocupe silla la 2 autobús y así sucesivamente

Comment: edita por favor y añade lo que has intentado

Comment: Parece una pregunta duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45508/como-eliminar-un-elemento-especifico-de-un-array?fromen=5767325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eliminar elementos de un `array` tienes varias maneras.

Para eliminar el último `array.pop()`

```js
var j = ['coche','mesa','silla','autobús'];
j.pop();
console.log(j)
```

Para eliminar el primero `array.shift()`

```js
var j = ['coche','mesa','silla','autobús'];
j.shift();
console.log(j)
```

Para eliminar eliminar un elemento sabiendo la posición  `array.splice(posición,numero de elementos a eliminar)`

```js
var j = ['coche','mesa','silla','autobús']; //RECORDAMOS QUE LOS ARRAY EMPIEZAN POR LA POSICIÓN 0
j.splice(2,1); //QUITAMOS ELEMENTO POSICIÓN 2, SOLO UNO
console.log(j)
```